# AutoMapper how to map a CamelCase Dictionary<string, object> to a PascalCase C# object

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to map a `Dictionary<string, object>` where properties are keyed with Camel casing to a C# object with Pascal casing:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
var dto = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "id", id.ToString() },
    { "value", "some value" },
};

var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { }).CreateMapper();
var result = mapper.Map<TestClass>(dto);

var expected = new TestClass {
    Id = id,
    Value = "some value",
};

result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

If I put the dictionary keys as PascalCase, it works out of the box. I'm guessing I need a custom [`INamingConvention`](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html?highlight=NamingConvention#naming-conventions), but the documentation isn't quite clear about what it should be like...

Can someone help me with that?

*using Automapper v7.0.1*

*Yes, I could do it the long way and map it manually, I know*

---

*Edit*

There is a closed issue in AutoMapper's github repo: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2903

Comment: Dynamic mapping doesn't consider the regular configuration, so that's not possible. You can have an extra step to translate the strings.

Comment: I wouldn't mind having a `CreateMap<Dictionary<string, object>, TestClass>()` statement, just not having to map each field manually. Does that help?

Comment: No. You have to translate the strings to PascalCase or take another approach.

Comment: Ah! You're saying before calling `map()` convert to the dictionary keys to PascalCase keys... but that would require copying the whole dictionary to a new one. :/