# Mapping of dynamic / Dictionary<string, object> to class with some different property names with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

i want to map a Dictionary or ExpandoObject to a class. 
Problem is that the class has different Names which should be recognized by AutoMapper via `RecognizePrefixes("SomePrefix")` and some properties should be mapped "by hand". i want to keep the "by hand" part close to zero and leave the mapping and property detection stuff to AutoMapper.

An example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OtherPropName { get; set; }
}

var d = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "SomePrefixId", Guid.NewGuid() },
    { "SomePrefixName", "My Name" },
    { "SomePrefixProp", "Some Value" },
}

var customMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { nameof(MyClass.OtherPropName), "SomePrefixProp" },
};

var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.RecognizePrefixes(prefix);
    var map = c.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, MyClass>(MemberList.Destination);

    if (customMap != null)
    {
        foreach (var pair in customMap)
        {
            map.ForMember(pair.Key, m => m.MapFrom(src => src[pair.Value]));
        }
    }
    map.ForAllMembers(m => m.MapAtRuntime());
});
```

with this code the only thing i get mapped is the property explicitly specified, but the `map.ForAllMembers(m => m.MapAtRuntime())` has no effect on the mapping. all other properties are null / have their default value. so i could determine the properties myself and do with custom mapping code but i thought it might be possible to avoid that.
i read that Dynamic and ExpandoObject [support](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html?highlight=dynamic) is there in AutoMapper but i dont get how to customize the mapping to my needs...

any help is much appreciated! :)
thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52430461/automapper-how-to-map-a-camelcase-dictionarystring-object-to-a-pascalcase-c-s

Comment: ok, so theres no way to do it with automapper alone and i have to match the property names myself. thanks for your answer though :)